# 'Merging' multiple rows with NULLs into rows with distinct sums

Tags: sql

Imagine the following table

```
| EEID | CODE1 | VALUE1 | CODE2 | VALUE2 |
|------|-------|--------|-------|--------|
| 001  | ABC   | 10     | NULL  | 0      |
| 001  | ABC   | 5      | NULL  | 0      |
| 001  | DEF   | 2      | NULL  | 0      |
| 001  | NULL  | 0      | 123   | 3      |
| 001  | NULL  | 0      | 123   | 6      |
| 001  | NULL  | 0      | 456   | 4      |
| 001  | NULL  | 0      | 789   | 1      |
```

Trying to avoid vendor specific functions, what is the best way to 'merge' this down using SQL to look like the following

```
| EEID | CODE1 | VALUE1 | CODE2 | VALUE2 |
|------|-------|--------|-------|--------|
| 001  | ABC   | 15     | 123   | 9      |
| 001  | DEF   | 2      | 456   | 4      |
| 001  | NULL  | 0      | 789   | 1      |
```

Basically I need to be able to sum the distinct values in the CODEx columns.

Comment: Why is 123 linked to ABC not DEF?

Comment: @MartinSmith there's no need for it to be linked to any of the CODE1 columns explicitly. .

Comment: In your result it is though. Would having ABC in the same result row as 456 and DEF with 123 be equally valid?

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, either would work fine in the result

Comment: How code2 and value2 is formed? Otherwise you can use partition in sql server.

Comment: Why i code1 null is allowed after grouping and in code2 you expect null to be merged in other code? This is inconsistent logic.

Comment: Why: 001 - DEF - 2 - 456 - 3 instead of 001 - DEF - 2 - 456 - 4?

Comment: @Kacper since there is an extra distinct value `789` in the `CODE2` column this data can't be discarded and needs to have its own row

Comment: @JoeTaras my mistake, fixed it in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.EEID, T2.EEID) AS EEID,
       CODE1,
       VALUE1,
       CODE2,
       VALUE2
FROM   (SELECT EEID,
               CODE1,
               SUM(VALUE1)                        AS VALUE1,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CODE1) AS RN
        FROM   YourTable
        WHERE  CODE1 IS NOT NULL
        GROUP  BY EEID,
                  CODE1) T1
       FULL JOIN (SELECT EEID,
                         CODE2,
                         SUM(VALUE2)                        AS VALUE2,
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CODE2) AS RN
                  FROM   YourTable
                  WHERE  CODE2 IS NOT NULL
                  GROUP  BY EEID,
                            CODE2) T2
         ON  ON T1.RN = T2.RN AND T1.EEID = T2.EEID;
```

It doesn't use any vendor specific functions though MySQL hasn't got around to implementing window functions (or full join for that matter) yet.

Or another way.

```
SELECT EEID,
       MAX(CODE1)  AS CODE1,
       SUM(VALUE1) AS VALUE1,
       MAX(CODE2)  AS CODE2,
       SUM(VALUE2) AS VALUE2
FROM   (SELECT EEID,
               CODE1,
               VALUE1,
               CODE2,
               VALUE2,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EEID ORDER BY CASE WHEN CODE1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Code1) AS RN1,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EEID ORDER BY CASE WHEN CODE2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Code2) AS RN2
        FROM   YourTable) T
GROUP  BY EEID,
          CASE
            WHEN CODE1 IS NULL
              THEN RN2
            ELSE RN1
          END
HAVING COALESCE(MAX(CODE1), MAX(CODE2)) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Wow this seems really good, and it works for the case of 2 columns.

Comment: (didn't mean to press enter) now if you add a 3rd, and flip the case statements to NOT NULLs I was able to get it to work for 3 columns. This is Great! Thank YOU! My window function skills have improved!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum the values in the different columns, I would suggest a different output structure:

```
select eeid, code1, 'code1' as which, sum(value1)
from t
where code1 is not null
group by eeid, code1
union all
select eeid, code2, 'code2' as which, sum(value2)
from t
where code2 is not null
group by eeid, code2;
```

This puts the values in different rows, but it is a much simpler solution to your problem.

This can be extended to a pivot, by using `group by` and `row_number()`:

```
select eeid, max(code1) as code1, max(value1) as value1,
       max(code2) as code2, max(value2) as value2
from ((select eeid, code1, sum(value1) as value1, NULL as code2, NULL as value2,
              row_number() over (partitionby eeid order by code1) as seqnum
       from t
       where code1 is not null
       group by eeid, code1
      ) union all
      (select eeid, NULL, NULL, code2, sum(value2)
              row_number() over (partition by eeid order by code2) as seqnum
       from t
       where code2 is not null
       group by eeid, code2
      )
     ) t12
group by eeid, seqnum;
```